# underbrace in the ket symbol makes it be enlarged in a bad way

Tags: equations

I have used:

```
\underbrace{\ket{0..0}}_{N}
```

and it results in

[image]

When I use `\ket{\underbrace{0..0}_{N}}` I have

[image]

Both of them are undesired!!! I just want to have the first symbol but with `N` be in the `ket` as:

[image]

How can I reach that?

Comment: Please explain how `\ket` is defined? And now you know why we generally do not recommend defining macros with auto scaling fences.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I define `\ket` by `\usepackage{physics}`

Comment: With `\usepackage{braket}` instead of  `\usepackage{physics}` works fine

Comment: Also with `|\underbrace{0..0}_{N} \rangle` you can do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `physics` package loves automatic scaling, which is one the
reasons why I don't like it. Anyway, it provides a starred version with no automatic scaling.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{physics}
\begin{document}
$\ket*{\underbrace{0..0}_{N}}$ vs.\ $\ket{\underbrace{0..0}_{N}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively you can use the `braket` package; personally I define `\ket` with `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` from `mathtools`.

Comment: Thank you so muchhhhhhhh